# How to query the build-in IoT-Hub of Azure Digital Twins?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-digital-twins

As far as I understand, every instance of Azure Digital Twins Preview brings its own IoT-Hub. A normal Azure IoT-Hub I could query like this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-query-language):

```
SELECT * FROM devices
```

How do I query the built in IoT-Hub of Azure Digital Twins?
Or isn't it possible to access this IoT-Hub and I always have to use the Digital Twins REST-API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current preview of Azure Digital Twins does not allow you to query the IoT Hub. However, at Microsoft Build, a new version of the preview was announced. This will change the structure of the Digital Twins itself and also allow you to bring your own Azure IoT Hub to integrate with. In the [Build Book Of News](https://news.microsoft.com/build-2020-book-of-news/#151-azure-digital-twins-adds-expanded-digital-representation-capabilities-), it is stated that this preview should come this summer.